# About the nomenclature: manganate or manganite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, solid-state-chemistry

I am a bit confused about the correct name of $\mathrm{LaMnO}_3$. Is it lanthanium manganate or lanthanum manganite?

I was assuming that since $\mathrm{SrTiO}_3$ is called strontium titanate, $\mathrm{LaMnO}_3$ would then be called lanthanium manganate, but I got confused when I heard a collegue referring to it as manganite and after reading a [wikiepdia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum_strontium_manganite) on $\mathrm{La}_x\mathrm{Sr}_{1-x}\mathrm{MnO}_3$ where they also used the term manganite.

Which is the correct form, or are they simply interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go down the ladder.  $\ce{KMnO4}$ is permanganate, Mn(VII).  $\ce{K2MnO4}$ is manganate, Mn(VI).  $\ce{K4MnO4}$ is manganite, Mn(IV).  $\ce{LaMnO3}$ is called both manganate and manganite, but Mn(III). In a proper world it should be lower than that manganite.  They are pedagogically both wrong if it is La(III).

http://dictionary.sensagent.com/potassium%20manganite/en-en/

Manganese oxidation state nomenclature is a real world mess. Drawing nomenclature parallels to Cl(VII) and downward is not valid.  Drawing nomenclature parallels to titanium is poor, for Ti(IV) is the highest common oxidation state.  $\ce{SrO + TiO2}$ gives $\ce{SrTiO3}$, properly called titanate, for it is Ti(IV) on both sides.

Organic had the same problem. The highest valence carbocation was tricoordinate, hence a carbonium ion.  Magic Acid gave $\ce{CH5^+}$.  Carbonium ions were renamed carbenium ions to general confusion.  Then, $\ce{CH6^{2+}}$.  Organic dropped the ball with direction of optical rotation versus geometric left and right.  It was flat out stupid designating *E* ("*trans*") and *Z* ("*cis*") olefins.  The designation should have been abstract rather than language-originated.

Comment: The last paragraph of your answer does not seem to have anything to do with with the admittedly clunky nomenclature of the metal oxyanions.

Comment: Also, your statement about optical isomerism is confusing, given that the direction of rotatation of plane-polarized light is [generally unrelated to the absolute spatial geometry of the chiral molecule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levorotation_and_dextrorotation)

Comment: Do better: http://www.mazepath.com/uncleal/norbors.gif  http://www.mazepath.com/uncleal/norone.png P3(1)21 quartz and P3(2)21 berlinite are both levorotatory despite being opposite geometric hands, J. Appl. Crystallogr. 19, 108 (1986). CIP notation flips within unchanged geometry (L-(S)-alanine, L-(R)-cysteine). Achiral PhCOCH3 impurity changes resolved PhCH(OH)CH3 optical rotation, J. Org Chem. 38(10), 1870 (1973).